# getElementsByTagName method in JavaScript ---not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function changeStyling() {
  var para = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  para[0].style.fontSize = 25;
  para[1].style.fontSize = "red";
}
```

```html
<p>This is the paragrap 1</p>
<p>This is the paragrap 1</p>
<p>This is the paragrap 1</p>
<p>This is the paragrap 1</p>
<p>This is the paragrap 1</p>
<p>This is the paragrap 1</p>
<p>This is the paragrap 1</p>

<button onclick="changeStyling()">click</button>
```

Comment: `.fontSize = "red"`... 0_o

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with `getElementsByTagName`, here is instead what is wrong:

- For the font size, you need to specify a unit, e.g. **`px`**.
- To set the color, obviously setting *fontSize* to a *color* is not going to work....

Improved code:

```js
function changeStyling() {
  var para = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  para[0].style.fontSize = "25px";
  para[1].style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<p>This is paragraph 0</p>
<p>This is paragraph 1</p>
<p>This is paragraph 2</p>
<p>This is paragraph 3</p>

<button onclick="changeStyling()">click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `px` for font size

```js
function changeStyling() {
  var para = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  para[0].style.color = 'red';
  para[1].style.fontSize = '24px';

}
```

```html
<p>This is the paragrap 1</p>
<p>This is the paragrap 1</p>
<p>This is the paragrap 1</p>
<p>This is the paragrap 1</p>
<p>This is the paragrap 1</p>
<p>This is the paragrap 1</p>
<p>This is the paragrap 1</p>

<button onclick="changeStyling()">
    click
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName` is working as expected . but fontSize need a `string`. Also 
to add color you need to color css property

```js
function changeStyling() {
  var para = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  para[0].style.fontSize = '25px';
  para[1].style.color = "red";


}
```

```html
<p>This is the paragrap 1</p>
<p>This is the paragrap 1</p>
<p>This is the paragrap 1</p>
<p>This is the paragrap 1</p>
<p>This is the paragrap 1</p>
<p>This is the paragrap 1</p>
<p>This is the paragrap 1</p>

<button onclick="changeStyling()">
     click
 </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function changeStyling() {


  var para = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  // console.log(para);
  para[0].style.fontSize = '25px';
  para[1].style.color = "red";


}
```

```html
<p> asdASDas </p>
<p> asdASDas </p>
<p> asdASDas </p>
<p> asdASDas </p>

<button onclick="changeStyling()"> push me </button>
```

Try it, i push inside the fontSize a string in pixel and color a string with red.

Answer (score 0):

You've put wrong styles

```
para[0].style.fontSize = "25px"; // string with px
para[1].style.color = "red"; // color, instead of fontSize
```